# I installed node.js v5.12.0 but the version showing v0.12.2

Tags: node.js

I installed Node.js from (https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/node-v5.12.0-x64.msi), but the issue is , its showing version v0.12.2 instead of v5.12.0 which is required.
I try to  update the node.js 5.2 installer but still showing version v0.12.2. 
I have uninstalled Node.js and reinstall node-v5.12.0-x64.msi but still it’s not updated. Due to this am not able to run further commands for Ionic environmental setup.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Open a terminal and type `where node`

It should point to an old version of node (v0.12.2) still installed on your computer, for example `C:\bin\node`.

As Node.js is portable, you can have multiple versions on your computer.

If it cannot be uninstalled, simply delete `C:\bin\node` folder. 
Then:

- Open **Windows System Properties/Advanced system properties**
- Click on **Environment variables** and edit **PATH** variable
- Remove inside its value the path of the old version of node (`C:\bin\node` in our example).
- Re-install Node v5.

**Close your terminal** and open a new one then type `where node`, it should point to Node.js v5

Comment: I am installing Node.js, it is taking path like "C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming". Is it fine or not

Comment: Did you follow my steps ? What is the console output of the very first command `where node` ?

Comment: most answers do not point towards changing the environment variables path...thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you have an old Node version for x86 platform, and you are installing a newer version for 64 bit. Remove the path to the x86 from the Paths env variable, or move it to after the 64 bit path.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

1. List node.js installatios using nvm:

   **nvm ls**
2. High chance the version you tried to install is also listed
3. Select the version to use using nvm

   **nvm use**

Answer (score 0):

(Not a direct solution)

You can try to install using `nvm`

Uninstall nodejs and follow the instruction from https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

Comment: Is it possible to update Node.js version from command prompt.

Comment: `nvm` allows you to install any version of `node` from the command line.
Bonus Tip: You can use `Git Bash` to run some linux commands in Windows (like curl)